# Rich card properties markdown formatting

Tags: c#, botframework

I have problem with markdown formatting of Text property in Hero card. Here is code sample:

```
HeroCard heroCard = new HeroCard()
{
    Text= $"**Place1**: Berlin \n\n**Place2**: Hamburg",
    Buttons = cardButtons
};
```

It doesn't make line brakes. Also tried \r\n, works neither. It looks like this:

[image]

How can I put text on the bottom of the hero card?

Comment: Have the same problem, you can specifiy markdown in the text property of the containing message, but markdown doesn't work in the text properties of attachment items - e.g. Title or Subtitle on a HeroCard.

Comment: The native capabilities of each channel vary substantially.  Which channel are you wanting to do this with?

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, this is down to both the channel (client - e.g. emulator, skype, facebook, your own directline client) implementing markdown support, since the text is sent as markdown in the json response.

However, *at the moment* you'll probably find that both the emulator and skype will render markdown on the message's "text" element but will ignore markdown on the attachment's "text" elements, e.g.

```
HeroCard heroCard = new HeroCard()
{
    Text= "Booo - no *markdown* supported here",
    Buttons = cardButtons
};
```

vs

```
var reply = activity.CreateReply("**Lovely lovely markdown**\n\n *yey!*");

var heroCard = new HeroCard()
{
    Text = "Booo - no *markdown* supported here",
    Buttons = cardButtons
};

reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment> {
  hero.ToAttachment()
};
```

I show a few examples of rich conversation cards [here](http://robinosborne.co.uk/2016/07/18/rich-botframework-conversation-cards/), and how they render on emulator vs skype desktop vs skype app va skype web, in case that helps.