# Teams Bot - Markdown In Cards Not Rendered

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-graph-teams

I have a problem with text formatting in cards on my Teams bot.

- When I send formatted text in text messages, the message is correctly formatted
- When I send formatted text in cards, the message is correctly formatted when testing with the bot emulator
- When I send formatted text in cards, the message is **not** formatted when testing with my normal Teams desktop client

Example sending a formatted text message:

```cs
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("test **with** _formatting_"), cancellationToken);
```

Example sending a card with formatted text:

```cs
var welcomeCard = new HeroCard
{
    Title = "Welcome",
    Text = "test **with** _formatting_"
};
var welcomeActivity = MessageFactory.Attachment(new Attachment
{
    ContentType = HeroCard.ContentType,
    Content = welcomeCard
});
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(welcomeActivity, cancellationToken);
```

When testing with my Teams client, the markdown is displayed verbatim: `test **with** _formatting_`

One more thing I should mention is that I'm "installing" the bot through the [developer portal](https://dev.teams.microsoft.com) clicking the "Preview in Teams" button.

Has anyone had this issue? How can I fix it?

Note that I also tried with HTML but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, Teams does not render markdown in the attachment's text elements (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39853847/1322336)).